# Solve a matrix (that returns a lower matrix) with any dimension using loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, matrix

How do I create a function that can solve a matrix (that returns a lower matrix) with any dimension using loops?

I have tried if functions for different square matrices (1, 2, 3, 4 etc) but I need some type of loop as I would need to go on forever.

Comment: Can't you use `lower.tri` (without loops)

Comment: I'm actually trying to find the cholesky decomposition of any size matrix without using the chol() function. I worked out the steps for each size but it is taking to long so I thought a loop would work?

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it?